# nslookup response is a lot slower compared to Resolve-DnsName cmdlet's response

Tags: powershell, nslookup

I have been trying to measure the DNS latency using PowerShell.

I want to check the DNS response time and want to skip the local resolver cache, so I used `nslookup` and it works fine except when I compared the results with `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet's response.

```
(Measure-Command { Resolve-DnsName www.google.com -DnsOnly }).TotalMillisecond
```

NOTE: I am using `-DnsOnly` argument to ensure that `Resolve-DnsName` uses DNS protocol only for name resolution.

`Resolve-DnsName` returns response in ~10 ms while `nslookup` returns response after >100ms

I am not sure how `Resolve-DnsName` internally works, but I am not sure which result to rely on.

Comment: I believe Resolve-DnsName is using cached results while nslookup is actually making a request to DNS servers.

Comment: That's what I also initially thought, but then `Resolve-DnsName` documentation indicates passing `-DnsOnly` argument forces it to send request to DNS serves which implies it skips the cache.

Comment: It implies it, but who knows if that option is actually working. I would maybe try to flush your DNS and see what happens. Maybe try specifying the DNS server in both commands.

Comment: So I flushed my DNS cache and only added about 9 ms to my Resolve-DnsName. I'm able to duplicate this behavior.

Comment: I have passed DNS servers in both the commands but no difference in result.

Comment: I think the time difference you observed is because with `nslookup` you're spawning a new process, which is not the case with `Resolve-DnsName`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Resolve-DnsName` instead of `nslookup`.

See: [The new nslookup: Resolve-DnsName](https://sid-500.com/2017/07/10/the-new-nslookup-resolve-dnsname/).

You are seeing the speed improvement because `Resolve-DnsName` is a brand new native PowerShell command that after being loaded, runs inside the PowerShell instance. `nslookup` is an executable that has to be loaded and ran in a new thread etc. This allows for `Resolve-DnsName` to run much faster, and with less overhead. Also, because `Resolve-DnsName` is a native PowerShell command, it has many more options open to you than `nslookup`.

Comment: What I am trying to measure is DNS response time. Is there any way to measure that?

Comment: I think that `Resolve-DnsName` would give you the closest, correct, response time that you are looking for. Conceptually, the DNS response should be nearly the same for both commands, since `nslookup` is 90ms+ slower that's all caused by the overhead of running the command. When I was running some tests, `Resolve-DnsName` came pretty close to `ping` response times which conceptually should be very close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Nslookup does not look at NRPT table: Get-DnsClientNrptRule

-Resolve-DnsName does look at the table

-DNS queries from a client machine query NRPT

-For this reason, Resolve-DNS should be used instead of nslookup

-Another solution is to use DIG instead of nslookup